# When I rotate an object how do I rotate back?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, rotation, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm on a code/maths task where I need to rotate a shape to 0 degrees and then back to whatever degrees it was at in the first place.

The following method:

```
    function rotateAroundOrigin(xPos:Number, yPos:Number, angle:Number, origin:Point):Point {
        var point:Point = new Point();
        angle *= Math.PI / 180;
        point.x = Math.cos(angle) * (xPos - origin.x) + Math.sin(angle) * (yPos - origin.y) + origin.x;
        point.y = Math.sin(angle) * (xPos - origin.x) - Math.cos(angle) * (yPos - origin.y) + origin.y;
        return point;
    }
```

Is invoked twice like so:

```
var rotatePoint:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
var rotatePointBack:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
```

It works fine but it doesn't make sense that it works because the degrees value is "-90" both times it's rotated. It should be "-90" to rotate one way and then "90" to rotate back to where it was in the first place.

Anyone have any ideas how I can modify the "rotateAroundOrigin" method so you can invoke with "-90" then with "90" like so?

```
var rotatePoint:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
var rotatePointBack:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, 90, midPoint);
```

Comment: With the current signs, the operation is a reflection about a line with slope angle `angle/2`. Applying it twice should return the original point.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL could you please expand on this? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var rotatePoint:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
> var rotatePointBack:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
> ```

It looks like you're just doing the same thing twice: rotating the point (30, 30) around midPoint. Consider this:

```
var rotatePoint:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(30, 30, -90, midPoint);
var rotatePointBack:Point = rotateAroundOrigin(rotatePoint.x, rotatePoint.y, 90, midPoint);
```

**EDIT:** I also noticed that you mixed up some signs in the rotation method. Try this:

```
function rotateAroundOrigin(xPos:Number, yPos:Number, angle:Number, origin:Point):Point {
    var point:Point = new Point();
    angle *= Math.PI / 180;
    point.x = Math.cos(angle) * (xPos - origin.x) - Math.sin(angle) * (yPos - origin.y) + origin.x;
    point.y = Math.sin(angle) * (xPos - origin.x) + Math.cos(angle) * (yPos - origin.y) + origin.y;
    return point;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's does not work though. The issue is something in the maths in "rotateAroundOrigin" method.

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg I just edited the answer with the rotateAroundOrigin method fixed, see if that works for you.

Comment: Hhhmm that formula's giving me some strange issues when rotating to some angles like 222 degrees for example.